# getaddrinfo error Device or resource busy

Tags: c, coap, dtls

I am trying to run FreeCoap (https://github.com/keith-cullen/FreeCoAP) to be able to communicate with COAP and DTLS on a Intel Galileo gen. 2 board. I have seen that out of the box tests compile and run correctly (as long as I have been able to test by now).

I have seen that it is prepared to run over IPv6. I am no expert on it, but I have seen that it has the value host configured as ::1, what I understand is the localhost. When I have tried to change it to IPv4, that is 127.0.0.1 or the actual IP address of the board I am getting errors.

I have seen that it uses netdb.h to create the server.

```
#include <netdb.h> 
...    
#define HOST                 "127.0.0.1"  /**< Host address to listen on */
#define PORT                 "12436"  
...

unsigned char msg_id[2] = {0};
struct addrinfo hints = {0};
struct addrinfo *list = NULL;
struct addrinfo *node = NULL;

hints.ai_flags = 0;
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;      /* value = 2 preferred socket domain */
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;  /* value = 3 preferred socket type */
hints.ai_protocol = 0;           /* preferred protocol (3rd argument to socket()) - 0 specifies that any protocol will do */
hints.ai_addrlen = 0;            /* must be 0 */
hints.ai_addr = NULL;            /* must be NULL */
hints.ai_canonname = NULL;       /* must be NULL */
hints.ai_next = NULL;            /* must be NULL */
ret = getaddrinfo(HOST, PORT, &hints, &list);
```

As result of getaddrinfo what I get is a -16 value, indicating the following error:

```
Error  : Device or resource busy
```

I have tried searchig with `netstat -a` and there is no such port in use.

What I am missing? What resource is busy and not allowing me to get the address?

Comment: try to run the executable file with `sudo` privileges and see what happens.

Comment: I am already root. There is no sudo on Yocto Linux. If I run su and then the executable I get the same result